# (Ruby on Rails) Building a URL in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I'm new to Rails, so bear with me here.
I'm trying to build the following URL:

```
localhost:3000/products/toyota
```

So, the homepage (localhost:3000 when I run the project locally) and the products page (localhost:3000/products) already exist, but I'm trying to create a toyota page (localhost:3000/products/toyota). The Toyota page has its own view (haml page/javascript) independent of the products page.

So, I tried this in config/routes.rb

```
get 'toyota', to: 'static#products#toyota'
```

but the toyota_url takes me to localhost:3000/toyota instead of localhost:3000/products/toyota.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: it's `get 'my/full/path', to: ....` so try `get 'products/toyota', to: 'static#products#toyota'`

Comment: I'm sure it's painfully obvious that I'm new to Rails here, but then the url isn't toyota_url in your view anymore right? how do you get the url in your view?

Comment: oh just kidding it's products_toyota_url! thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: You are welcome, keep it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this instead

```
get '/products/toyota', to: 'static#products#toyota', as: 'toyota'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: follow up question...then it's not toyota_url anymore right? so in your views how do you get that url?

Comment: oh nevermind it's just products_toyota_url! Thanks so much for your help! Have a great day!

Comment: You can add `as: 'toyota'` to get `toyota_url`, edited the answer.

Comment: Actually, another issue just came up. So, as I said, I have separate views for both my products page and toyota page, but the toyota page is displaying the view from the products page

Comment: Don't you have `toyota.html.erb` file?

Comment: Yeah, I have a toyota.html.haml file and a toyota.js file but for some reason they're not loading in the sources window

Comment: You need to add that line above `resources :products` line in routes file

Comment: when I changed it to get 'products/toyota', to: 'static#toyota' it worked!

Comment: Ok, so you have a static_controller and in that controller one toyota action is there. I don't know why you wrote it like static#products#toyota in the first place. The syntax is controller#action.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment: it's `get 'my/full/path', to: ....` so try `get 'products/toyota', to: 'static#products#toyota', :as => 'toyota'`

But what I would recommend is the following. To keep it a bit more flexible - I assume you will have other vendors/products as well, create an action:

Route:

```
get 'products/:vendor', to: 'products#vendor'
```

Controller:

```
def vendor(id)
   @car_or_whatever = Product.find_by(....)     
end
```

View:

```
# file views/products/vendor.html.erb
<some fancy html>
   @car_or_whatever.name

   ... etc
```

From the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code